# What's the difference between "cheat" and "deceive"?

Tags: differences

Is there any nuance that exists between the two words? I would like to hear from linguistics if there is any subtle difference.

Answer (score 3):

Deceit means dishonest behavior meant to trick someone. Deceit often involve telling a lie and/or omitting facts. To [deceive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deceive) is to use deceit; that is, is to cause someone to believe something false, usually to your advantage. For example, "the car salesman deceived the customer about the value of the car."

To [cheat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheat) is to act dishonestly or break a rule or law to gain an advantage. For example, "he cheated at chess by moving a piece while his opponent wasn't looking." You can also cheat someone out of something, like "he was cheated out of his money on eBay because the seller never sent the item."

Deceiving is similar to lying, and cheating is similar to stealing or breaking the rules. A technique you can use: if you can rewrite the sentence using "lying," you should probably use "deceive;" If you can rewrite the sentence using "stealing" or "breaking the rules," you should probably use "cheating."

Example:

> She ____ by using extra cards during the game.

"She *broke the rules* by using extra cards" makes more sense here than "She *lied* by using extra cards," so it should be "She cheated by using extra cards during the game."

Example:

> She ____ her mother about where she was going when she said "to the library."

"She *lied to*" her mother" makes more sense here than "She *stole from* her mother" or "She *broke the rules*", so it should be "She deceived her mother."

Note that cheat can also be used to describe narrowly escaping something, like "she cheated death when she survived the car crash without a seat-belt."

Note also that, according to the Merriam-Webster definition linked above, defining "deceive" as "cheat" is obsolete (no longer user, outdated).

Answer (score -1):

A five-year-old girl when playing cards would say to her brother: You are cheating! Years later at school she would learn the Latin verb to deceive that has the same meaning. And she would have difficulties with the curious spelling ei for long i.

Comment: I don't see how this helps figure out the difference between the words. Are you saying "cheating" is a childish word? Would you really say to "You deceived me!" to someone who broke the rules of a card game?